# Are non-static fields static until they're changed in Java?

Tags: java, memory, reference

Let's consider the following code:

```
public class Testing {
    static int i = 47;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Testing t1 = new Testing();
        Testing t2 = new Testing();
        System.out.println(t1.i == t2.i);
```

I'm creating a static field belonging to the Testing class and this field is shared among the two instances of that class `t1` and `t2` as well. Then I test if they reference to the same value in memory and indeed, they do, the result is true. And that's clear for me.

However, if I delete the static keyword from the declaration of `int i`, something unexpected happen.

```
public class Testing {
    int i = 47;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Testing t1 = new Testing();
        Testing t2 = new Testing();
        System.out.println(t1.i == t2.i);
```

I would expect the two instances `t1` and `t2` to both have 47 as a value of their field but their fields be in different memory addresses. But surprisingly, when test for `t1.i == t2.i` I get true as well in this case - why? The field `int i = 47;` is not static anymore so I would expect it to be in different memory addresses for every instance of the class but the equality yields true.

Comment: `==` tests for value equality.

Comment: `int` is a "primitive", not a reference.  You are simply testing the integer values.

Answer (score 6):

An `int` is a primitive type, not a reference type. The condition `t1.i == t2.i` does not test for reference equality -- there is no reference in the first place here. It simply compares the values and in this case, both have the value `47`.

If you had a member field that is not a primitive, the result would be different, for example:

```
public class Testing {
    Integer i = new Integer(47);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Testing t1 = new Testing();
        Testing t2 = new Testing();
        System.out.println(t1.i == t2.i);   // false
    }
}
```

In this case, each instance has a different reference to an `Integer` object created using the `new` keyword which invokes a constructor, and the condition `t1.i == t2.i` compares these two references.

Comment: And if you do want to test for reference equality, I believe there's a `referenceEquals()` in Java.

Comment: @BrianJ I don't think you have access to the memory address of native types.

Comment: @AbbéRésina Turns out I was thinking of C# anyway.  Java doesn't have a `referenceEquals`, it uses `==`, which means you must be right.

Answer (score 2):

The identity of an int is differnet from the identity of objects.

Objects identity is derived from beeing the one and same object,
primitive type identity is derived from identic values (47 == 47).

If you change the code to `Integer i = 47;` then the `==` will not unbox the Integers, but compare object references and the result will be false.

If you initialize the Integer as shown (with literal 47), the autoboxing will select the Integer object from an internal cache. On identity compare (==), the result is true. If you set at least one of the Integers with a Integer i = new Integer(47)`, the compare will fail, because you now have a new object created. The same applies if you get out of the cache range, initializing the Integer with a literal outside the signed byte range. The runtime will then create a new Integer for the literal and the identity compare will return false.

I think this is a bad caveat in unboxing, making it hard to find the issue, if you really wanted to compare the reference of the Integer not the values. 
I have used the following code to illustrate the different behavior. I now think it is bad habit to simply instantiate `Integer` with int literals and rely on autoboxing. This will have subtile changes in runtime behavior. Additionally, if you handle objects, be on the save side and compare with `.equals()`.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        Integer h = new Integer(47); // Object created w/o boxing
        Integer i = new Integer(47);
        Integer j = 47; // Object created with boxing
        Integer k = 47; // due to  caching, this is the same Integer

        Integer j2 = 247; // Object created with boxing
        Integer k2 = 247; // no caching, these are different Integers

        int l = 47;  // primitives 
        int m = 47;

        // compare two explicit Objects 
        System.out.println((h == i) ? "true" : "false"); // false

        // compare one explicit Object with a autoboxed Object
        // compare is reference compare
        System.out.println((h == j) ? "true" : "false"); // false
        System.out.println((j == h) ? "true" : "false"); // false

        // compare two autoboxed Objects, compare is by reference
        // because value was in cache range, the Integers are identical
        System.out.println((k == j) ? "true" : "false"); // true 

        // compare two autoboxed Objects, compare is by reference
        // because value was not in cache range, these are two Objects of type Integer
        System.out.println((k2 == j2) ? "true" : "false"); // false 

        // adding a primitive to the compare will
        // always compare by value
        System.out.println((i == l) ? "true" : "false"); // true
        System.out.println((m == l) ? "true" : "false"); // true
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I took the comments into account and updated my sample to have the unexpected caching of `intValue()` included.

Comment: Now I understand where I was wrong but I also checked your proposed solution (changing int to Integer) but the result is still true so it looks like an automatic conversion from Integer to int occurs.

Comment: Shouldn't be the case, according to oracle docs: "The == operator performs reference identity comparisons on Integer expressions and value equality comparisons on int expressions."

Comment: I have tested it, seems that the java compiler is smarted in unboxing than before.

Comment: @thst have a look at my answer to see what's happening behind the scene

Comment: @AbbéRésina Thanks for your explanation. I have updated my sample to reflect the intValue caching.

Answer (score 2):

There is already good answers on why your `==` test just works on native `int` even when you create 2 instances.

I just want to point some weird stuff the compiler can do behind the scene that can give counterintuitive results. Consider the following test:

```
public class Foo {
    final Integer i = 47;
    final Integer j = 1234;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Foo p = new Foo();
        Foo q = new Foo();
        System.out.println(p.i.equals(q.i));
        System.out.println(p.i == q.i);
        System.out.println(p.j.equals(q.j));
        System.out.println(p.j == q.j);
    }
}
```

You expect

- either `true, true, true, true` because compiler is smart at identifying that, even there are 2 instances of `Foo`, they have the same value for `i` and `j`.
- or `true, false, true, false`, because, after all, `i` and `j` are different instances of `Integer`, and `==` compares the reference values that should not be the same.

But the surprise is you actually get `true, true, true, false`. What the heck is the difference between `i` and `j`?

Well, if you look at the generated code with `javap -verbose Foo.class`, you see:

```
  stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
     0: aload_0
     1: invokespecial #11                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
     4: aload_0
     5: bipush        47
     7: invokestatic  #13                 // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    10: putfield      #19                 // Field i:Ljava/lang/Integer;
    13: aload_0
    14: sipush        1234
    17: invokestatic  #13                 // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
    20: putfield      #21                 // Field j:Ljava/lang/Integer;
    23: return
```

The compiler has generated code that use [Integer#valueOf(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)). And the doc states:

> This method will **always cache values** in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and **may cache other values** outside of this range.

This explains why the 2 instances of `Foo` actually share the same `Integer` object for `47`, but not for `1234`.

The moral is: beware of `==` when you are comparing objects. In most cases, what you want and need is `equals()`.

Answer (score 1):

All that `static` does is tell the interpreter that the object/variable is contained in that class alone, without any need to define an instance (Object) of that class before using it.

The reason this is happening is because the two variables contain the same value, as they are both `int`s with the value `47`, thus, comparing them reveals they are exactly the same.

If you wanted to compare the *equality* of two non-primitive classes, you can use this:

```
if(t1.equals(t2)){
...
}
```

Otherwise, if you wanted to compare the *class* of two objects/variables, you can do this by testing this:

```
if(t1.getClass() == t2.getClass()){
...
}
```

Or, if you wanted to check if it was an *instance* of another class (Extending or inheriting from it), you can use:

```
if(t1 instanceof int){
...
}
```

Comment: "As a rule of thumb, it is best to either put public, private, or protected before your variable definitions" - disagree, default visibility is sometimes expected